# AutoMapper: map entities to a destination with a suffix

Tags: automapper, automapper-7

Given the following example:

```
class Source:
int Id;
DateTimeOffSet StartDate;
DateTimeOffSet EndDate;
...

class Destination:
int Id;
DateTimeOffSet StartDate;
DateTimeOffSet StartDateUtc;
DateTimeOffSet EndDate;
DateTimeOffSet EndDateUtc;
...
```

How can I map both ways **all** source properties of type DateTimeOffSet of all my objects from/to their destination properties with the -Utc suffix? (the destination property without the suffix should stay unmapped)

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration.html#recognizing-pre-postfixes

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu can't get it to work destination -> source; AM uses Destination.StartDate instead of Destination.StartDateUtc (tried RecognizePostfixes/RecognizeDestinationPostfixes)

Comment: These things can be tricky. You can check the tests in the repo to get a better feel about how to use them.